# Entity framework foreign table not accessible in xaml code behind

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, ria, domainservices

I am attempting to pull an IQueryable from my DomainService class to my XAML code behind using RIA services.

The DomainService pulls from a BLL, which pulls from a DAL, which gets it from EF.

I cannot seem to access the foreign table in the XAML, but I can access it just fine in the DomainService method.

The DomainService method looks like this...

```
    public IQueryable<MenuHeader> GetMenuHeaders()
    {
        BusinessLogic.Employee blEmployee = new BusinessLogic.Employee();

        int employeeId = blEmployee.GetEmployeeIdFromUserName(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        var menuHeaders = blEmployee.GetEmployeeMenuHeaders(employeeId);
        // This works here!
        var menuHeaderItems = from mh in menuHeaders
                              select mh.MenuHeaderItems;
        return menuHeaders;
    }
```

In the XAML code behind, I call this method here:

...

```
EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();

EntitySet<MenuHeader> menuHeaders = employeeContext.MenuHeaders;            
employeeContext.Load(employeeContext.GetMenuHeadersQuery()).Completed += (s, e) =>
    {
        // This does NOT work here!
        var menuHeaderItems = from mh in menuHeaders
                              select mh.MenuHeaderItems; // <-- Not found
    };
```

...

How can I get this table up to my XAML code so I can databind to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that my Entity Model is not a part of my ASP.Net/RIA app.  It is only referenced in.

Since it is a reference, the DomainService won't auto-generate the metadata.  I had to manually create the metadata so that Silverlight knew what to expect.

Answer (score 0):

**Your sending and receiving code appear perfectly correct.** If the server side is correctly returning the entities in your test code, then something has gone terribly wrong. I have tried several variations and cannot get similar code to fail *ever*.

**As an aside, you have 3 options for accessing a collection returned from RIA services:**

**1. Use the specific collection in the context (as you did)**

```
EntitySet<MenuHeader> menuHeaders = employeeContext.MenuHeaders;
... // On Completed event
var menuHeaderItems = from mh in menuHeaders
                          select mh.MenuHeaderItems;
```

**2. Use the load operation Entities property**

```
EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
var LoadOp = employeeContext.Load(employeeContext.GetMenuHeadersQuery());
// Bind to LoadOp.Entities
```

**3. Use the Load() callback parameter**

```
EmployeeContext employeeContext = new EmployeeContext();
var LoadOp = employeeContext.Load(employeeContext.GetMenuHeadersQuery(),
      (cb) => 
      {
            // do something with cb.Entities here
      }, 
      false);
```

I prefer version 2 for lazy binding and 3 for any custom responses (just to keep the lines of code down).